# How to NOT INCREMENT in for loop after an exception was caught?

Tags: java

HERE are my teachers prompts:

> Put the TRY block with the CATCH clause INSIDE THE FOR/WHILE LOOP so if the SPECIFIC exception is thrown from
>   the constructor , you will display an error message, and NOT INCREMENT
>   the counter.

Here is my constructor and my code for this portion:

```
public CreditCardNumber(String id, String accNum) {
    this();
    if (id == null || accNum == null || id.length() != 6 || accNum.length() != 9 || 
        isDigit(id) == false || isDigit(accNum) == false) {

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Either parameter is null or has incorrect length or doesn't have all digits");
    } else {
        accountNum = accNum;
        issuerId = id;

        setCheckDigit();
    }
}
```

///

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
    try { 
        System.out.println("Enter an issuer ID# (6 digits) for element #" + i);
        String issuerId = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("Enter an account # (9 digits) for element #" + i);
        String accountNum = scanner.next();
        CreditCardNumber obj = new CreditCardNumber(issuerId, accountNum);
        obj.changeId(issuerId);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Input, Try Again!")
        continue;
    }
}
```

Now what I'm having trouble is how do you implement this code so that after the exception is caught, the code re-prompts the user to enter the value for the same i value the exception was caught in. Basically how do I NOT INCREMENT the loop after the exception is caught? I tried continue; method and the compiler says the code is unreachable. Please HELP!

Comment: If you have a choice of using either a for loop or a while loop, a while loop would make this a lot more intuitive.

Comment: How can I implement it in a while loop ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of incrementing your `i` in the third part of the for loop with the unary `++` operator, just do it at the end of the try block:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrLength;) { // removed here
    try { 
        System.out.println("Enter an issuer ID# (6 digits) for element #" + i);
        String issuerId = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("Enter an account # (9 digits) for element #" + i);
        String accountNum = scanner.next();
        CreditCardNumber obj = new CreditCardNumber(issuerId, accountNum);
        obj.changeId(issuerId);
        i++; // added here
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input, Try Again!"); // don't throw just print
    }
}
```

Also i would recommend to replace the boolean checks in your constructor in the form of

```
if(variable == false){...}
```

with just

```
if(!variable){...}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the same logic with a while loop.

```
int i = 0;
while (i < arrLength) {
    try { 
        System.out.println("Enter an issuer ID# (6 digits) for element #" + i);
        String issuerId = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("Enter an account # (9 digits) for element #" + i);
        String accountNum = scanner.next();
        CreditCardNumber obj = new CreditCardNumber(issuerId, accountNum);
        obj.changeId(issuerId);
        i++; 
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // print the error message instead of throwing an exception
        System.out.println("Invalid Input, Try Again!");
        // don't increment the counter.
    }
}
```

Note that I changed the `catch` block to just printing the error message instead of throwing an exception.

Answer (score 1):

In catch block when you catch Exception use `--i` to decrement loop counter.
The best way is incrementing loop counter if don't got exception and use continue when got exception.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
    try { 
        System.out.println("Enter an issuer ID# (6 digits) for element #" + i);
        String issuerId = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("Enter an account # (9 digits) for element #" + i);
        String accountNum = scanner.next();
        CreditCardNumber obj = new CreditCardNumber(issuerId, accountNum);
        obj.changeId(issuerId);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input, Try Again!")
        i--; //<- this what you want ignore fault input
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: but the `throw` in the `catch` will still jump out of the method, `i--` is unreachable (same problem as stated in question)